# RoR: How to seed an image to my database from a local file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Codecademy shows one can seed images via a url like (in seeds.rb):

```
t1 = Tag.create(title: "Beaches", image: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/learn-rails/img/beach01.jpg")
Destination.create(name: "Ipanema", description: "The beach of Ipanema is known for its elegant development and its social life.", image: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/learn-rails/img/beach02.jpg", tag_id: t1.id)
```

But what if I have a local file I would like to use instead? My file path is given in Ruby by

```
File.join(Rails.root,'db','images','Event1.jpg')
```

I tried using

```
image: File.open(File.join(Rails.root,'db','images','Event1.jpg'))
```

in place of

```
image: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/learn-rails/img/beach02.jpg"
```

but it didn't work.

Currently I'm accessing the image in the view using

```
<%= image_tag t.image %>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first wrap your head around some concepts:

1. You can't store the object returned by `File.open` or `File.new`. Those are just IO objects that reference a stream (more about it [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/IO.html#method-c-new)). At least you need to get the image's contents with `File.read` so that you can store them and use them later.
2. Once you have the image's contents in a variable you may store it in your database. Beware that this is a big element, and you may need to scale your storage.
3. Let's assume that you can retrieve this content from your db. How is `image_tag` supposed to know how to represent your stored data?

Once you have that figured out, you might want to analyze some options on how to actually implement it:

a. Store a binary blob or base 64 representation of your image. Before actually using it, write it in a local file and pass it as argument for image_tag. Cons: very inefficient. I put it as an option since it is what you're trying to do in the first place, but I don't think it is viable.  Databases are not optimized to hold large amounts of data in a single column entry (take this with a grain of salt, since it depends on the DB engine and the way you are querying the data). Also, the reading from DB/writing to local file is quite slow, and you need to serve that image as fast as you can.

b. Store a reference to the file, and save the image locally (could be put in `app/assets/images`, for example). Then you can reference it with `image_tag Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', t.filename)`. Cons: there's no straightforward way of knowing that your image is available.

c. As in your CodeAcademy example, save the image in an external service and save a URL reference to it. There are several services that are specially designed for that, such as AWS S3. These are highly optimized for serving images and files in general, that's why it is better than serving the image all by yourself. But when you are big enough as, say, StackOverflow, you might want to have your own storage service, since intensive usage might be better/cheaper than using an external service. So how to these external services do it? The may store it directly to disk. Then when you access that url a program serves that content just like another file, but putting the necessary headers so that your browser can interpret its contents (refer to concept 1. above). **Edit**: StackOverflow does use external services: imgur.com/gravatar.com, use the "Inspect Element" tool of your browser and see for yourself :)

Comment: Jihonora, I appreciate the care you took in your answer. Why does it either have to be inefficient or by filename? How does stack overflow store everyones profile images for instance? If they're not in a database where are they? Also, what exactly is inefficient about storing an image in a database, for instance how is it less efficient than storing it in app/assets?

Comment: @Dennis you're asking the right questions, keep it up and you'll learn a lot. I updated my answers to address them, although briefly. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

```
User.first.image.attach(io: File.open("db/seeds-images/me.jpg"), filename: "me.jpg")
```

Notes:

- I like to put some images inside a directly called db/seeds-images, but you can put them whereever you prefer.
- Answer based of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66302764/5783745)