# How to attach an Active Storage image from local hard disk from the rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am trying to learn how to attach an image from local hard disk to Active Storage. E.g.

```rb
User.last.images.attach("../../Downloads/me.jpg")
```

But I see

```
ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature: ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature
from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb:176:in `verify'
```

Answer (score 21):

The problem was you shouldn't just provide the file path, but instead give the file path to `File.open()` (the error message doesn't necessarily make that obvious).

Once that's out of the way, a `filename` must also be provided, so the full answer is:

```rb
User.last.images.attach(io: File.open("../../Downloads/me.jpg"), filename: "something")
```

Note: another user provided a more general approach:

```rb
User.last.images.attach(io: File.open("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/my_image.png"), filename: 'my_image.png', content_type: 'image/png')
```

Comment: Thanks. I needed content_type to make it works as well.